# Get a specific tag in a node?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm using Ruby, XPath and Nokogiri and trying to retrieve `d1` from the following XML:

```
<a>
  <b1>
    <c>
      <d1>01/11/2001</d1>
      <d2>02/02/2004</d2>
    </c>
  </b1>
</a>
```

This is my code in a loop:

```
rs = doc.xpath("//a/b1/c/d1").inner_text

puts rs
```

It returns nothing (No error).

I want to get the text in `<d1>`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Get a specific tag in a node?

Comment: How do you read the document

Answer (score 2):

You don't ask for the text content in your xpath query:

```
rs = doc.xpath('//a/b1/c/d1/text()')
```

Comment: `text()` doesn't return the text. It returns a Nokogiri::XML::Text node: `doc.xpath('//a/b1/c/d1/text()') # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ffc9e4c77d4 "01/11/2001">]`. To get at the inner text you still have to use an accessor like `text`: `doc.xpath('//a/b1/c/d1/text()').text # => "01/11/2001"` or `to_s`: `doc.xpath('//a/b1/c/d1/text()').to_s # => "01/11/2001"`. Also, `xpath` returns a NodeSet, so theoretically an array of nodes would be returned, which isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: You shouldn't use `//` on a root node.

Answer (score 2):

You're misusing XPath:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<a>
  <b1>
    <c>
      <d1>01/11/2001</d1>
      <d2>02/02/2004</d2>
    </c>
  </b1>
</a>
EOT

doc.at('/a/b1/c/d1').text # => "01/11/2001"
doc.at('//d1').text # => "01/11/2001"
```

`//` in XPath-ese means start at the top and look anywhere in your document. Instead, if you're supplying an explicit/absolute selector, start at the top of the document and drill down using `'/a/b1/c/d1'`. Or, do the simple thing and let the parser search through the document for that particular node using `//d1`. You can do that if you know there's a single instance of that node.

In my code above, I used `at` instead of `xpath`. `at` returns the first matching node, which is similar to using `xpath('//d1').first`. `xpath` returns a [NodeSet](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html), which is like an array of nodes, whereas `at` returns a [Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) only. Using `inner_text` on a NodeSet is likely to not give you the results you want, which would be the text of a particular node, so be careful there.

```
doc.xpath('/a/b1/c/d1/text()').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet

doc.xpath('//c').inner_text # => "\n      01/11/2001\n      02/02/2004\n    "
doc.xpath('/a/b1/c/d1').first.text # => "01/11/2001"
```

Look at the following lines. Instead of using XPath selectors, I used CSS, which tends to be more readable. Nokogiri supports both.

```
doc.at('d1').text # => "01/11/2001"
doc.at('a b1 c d1').text # => "01/11/2001"
```

Also, notice the type of data returned from these two lines:

```
doc.at('/a/b1/c/d1/text()').class # => Nokogiri::XML::Text
doc.at('/a/b1/c/d1').text.class # => String
```

While it might seem good/smart to tell the parser to locate the `text()` node inside `<d1>`, what will be returned isn't text, and will need to be accessed further to make it usable, so consider forgoing the use of `text()` unless you know exactly why you need it:

```
doc.at('/a/b1/c/d1/text()').text # => "01/11/2001"
```

Finally, Nokogiri has many methods used for locating nodes. As I said above, `xpath` returns a NodeSet and `at` returns a Node. `xpath` is really an XPath-specific version of Nokogiri's `search` method. `search`, `css` and `xpath` all return NodeSets. `at`, `at_css` and `at_xpath` all return Nodes. The CSS and XPath variants are useful when you have an ambiguous selector that you need to be used as CSS or XPath specifically. Most of the time Nokogiri can figure whether it's CSS or XPath on its own and will do the right thing, so it's OK to use the generic `search` and `at` for the majority of your coding. Use the specific versions when you have to specify one or the other.